# Check IF Exists in inner table of SQL that contains multiple union

Tags: sql-server, union-all

```
@sipcount= (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(SIP.[Total]),0) FROM 
                    (
                        SELECT COUNT(1) AS Total FROM [dbo].[MF_tblSundaramSIPDetails] AS [mtfsd] 
                            WHERE ISNULL([mtfsd].[TrxnType],'') = 'SYSTEMATIC PURCHASE' AND [mtfsd].[ClientFK] IN (SELECT NewspaperFK FROM dbo.Split(@ClientPK,',')) 
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT COUNT(1) AS Total FROM [dbo].[MF_tblCamsSIPDetails] AS [mtfsd] 
                            WHERE ISNULL([AUT_Trntyp],'') = 'P' AND [mtfsd].[ClientFK] IN (SELECT NewspaperFK FROM dbo.Split(@ClientPK,',')) 
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT COUNT(1) AS Total FROM [dbo].[MF_tblFranklinSIPDetails] AS [mtfsd] 
                            WHERE ISNULL([mtfsd].[isSipStp],'') = 'SIP' AND [mtfsd].[ClientFK] IN (SELECT NewspaperFK FROM dbo.Split(@ClientPK,',')) 
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT COUNT(1) AS Total FROM [dbo].[MF_tblKarvySIPDetails] AS [mtfsd] 
                            WHERE ISNULL([mtfsd].[TrType],'') = 'SIP' AND [mtfsd].[ClientFK] IN (SELECT NewspaperFK FROM dbo.Split(@ClientPK,','))
                    ) AS SIP)
```

now i want to check if exists in each Select Count(1) statements like below

```
@sipcount= (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(SIP.[Total]),0) FROM 
                    (if exists(select 1)
begin
SELECT COUNT(1) AS Total FROM [dbo].[MF_tblSundaramSIPDetails] AS [mtfsd] 
                                WHERE ISNULL([mtfsd].[TrxnType],'') = 'SYSTEMATIC PURCHASE' AND [mtfsd].[ClientFK] IN (SELECT NewspaperFK FROM dbo.Split(@ClientPK,',')) 
end
else
begin
SELECT COUNT(1) AS Total FROM [dbo].[MF_tblSundaramSIPDetails1] AS [mtfsd] 
                                WHERE ISNULL([mtfsd].[TrxnType],'') = 'SYSTEMATIC PURCHASE' AND [mtfsd].[ClientFK] IN (SELECT NewspaperFK FROM dbo.Split(@ClientPK,',')) 
end
                        ) AS SIP)
```

Comment: You can use AND EXISTS in the queries themselves.

Comment: please can u give example

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work for you. Check the  usage of AND EXISTS. You may have to format it and a bracket may be here and there, but this is how AND EXISTS works.

```
Select @sipcount= (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(SIP.[Total]),0) FROM ( 
SELECT COUNT(1) AS Total FROM [dbo].[MF_tblSundaramSIPDetails] AS [mtfsd] WHERE ISNULL([mtfsd].[TrxnType],'') = 'SYSTEMATIC PURCHASE' AND [mtfsd].[ClientFK] IN (SELECT NewspaperFK FROM dbo.Split(@ClientPK,',') 
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableName WHERE Column_Value = 'STR')
) UNION ALL
 SELECT COUNT(1) AS Total FROM [dbo].[MF_tblCamsSIPDetails] AS [mtfsd] WHERE ISNULL([AUT_Trntyp],'') = 'P' AND [mtfsd].[ClientFK] IN (SELECT NewspaperFK FROM dbo.Split(@ClientPK,',') AND EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 FROM TableName WHERE Column_Value = 'STR')) 
UNION ALL 
SELECT COUNT(1) AS Total FROM [dbo].[MF_tblFranklinSIPDetails] AS [mtfsd] WHERE ISNULL([mtfsd].[isSipStp],'') = 'SIP' AND [mtfsd].[ClientFK] IN (SELECT NewspaperFK FROM dbo.Split(@ClientPK,',') 
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableName WHERE Column_Value = 'STR')) 
UNION ALL 
SELECT COUNT(1) AS Total FROM [dbo].[MF_tblKarvySIPDetails] AS [mtfsd] WHERE ISNULL([mtfsd].[TrType],'') = 'SIP' AND [mtfsd].[ClientFK] IN 
(SELECT NewspaperFK FROM dbo.Split(@ClientPK,',') 
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableName WHERE Column_Value = 'STR')
) ) AS SIP)
```